# Connected to my Android VirtualBox installation with ADB, now how do I install an apk from Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, virtualbox

I used VirtualBox to create a virtual installation of the Android operating system (Android 4.0, downloaded from http://wwww.android-x86.org ).  After some effort, I managed to configure it to have internet access and to show up locally on my network, having its own local IP (192.168.1.115).  Next, I used the **adb** tool from Android's SDK on my host machine to connect to the virtual Android device successfully, using the following command:

```
adb connect 192.168.1.115
```

Now, I can install APK's using adb, using

```
adb install C:\path\to\myApp.apk
```

after first exporting a signed APK in Eclipse (I've found that unsigned APK's won't install via adb, instead giving an error message about a certificate or something).

This is fine and it works, but the process is extremely slow, since I have to go through the entire process of exporting in Eclipse, running the adb install command from my command line, and then finally switching to my virtual Android tablet and tapping on the application to run it.  My question is this: **Is there any easier way to configure Eclipse, such that I can build/install/run in one click (or even two clicks)?**  I miss the simplicity of choosing "Run as Android Application" and having the application immediately pop up in the Android simulator, but the simulator otherwise is much worse for testing.

Also note: I've read some guides that seem to claim that the device should appear inside of Eclipse's AVD list, but all I'm seeing there are my two simulator devices, not my VirtualBox Android installation, even though my host machine has used adb to connect to the device, and the device is showing up in the "adb devices" command as "device" (not as "offline" or anything else that could be problematic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

I had to right-click on the project, "Run As -> Run Configurations...".  Then, under "Android Application", click the name of my project, click the "Target" tab, and click "Always prompt to pick device."  And then click Run.

From the menu that pops up, my device is shown there and I can set it to be the default device, despite the device not showing up in the list of devices anywhere else (not even in the "Target" tab).

Now, clicking the usual "Run" button in Eclipse will take care of all of the steps of building the apk, installing it to the virtual device, and running it on the virtual device.